# Does promise-chaining guarantee that a callback of the next promise is called only after preceding one is finished?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I met an [article about promises in js](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html), where the author shows a piece of code:

```
// I want to remove() all docs
db.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then(function (result) {
  result.rows.forEach(function (row) {
    db.remove(row.doc);  
  });
}).then(function () {
  // I naively believe all docs have been removed() now!
});
```

and says

> What's the problem with this code? The problem is that the first
>   function is actually returning undefined, meaning that the second
>   function isn't waiting for db.remove() to be called on all the
>   documents. In fact, it isn't waiting on anything, and can execute when
>   any number of docs have been removed!

So, as I understood, if the second callback `function() {}` accepts no arguments, it actually doesn't wait for the end of the callback `function(result)`. Am I inferring correctly? Because when I run the following piece of code, it gives me an opposite result:

```
var array = [];
for ( let i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
    array.push(i);

var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000);
});

promise
.then(() => array.forEach(item => console.log(item)))
.then(() => console.log("invoked earlier"));
```

I wait for "invoked earlier" to appear in the middle of printed numbers. But doesn't matter how large the number of items is. "Invoked earlier" appears always at the end. Can someone explain me what I am missing? Maybe the article is outdated and something has changed since then?

Comment: For what I can see (and if I'm not mistaken)...you missed one thing: in the code the guy posted, you have a `forEach` and inside you have an asyncronous call... `db.remove()` this is the reason he said that the code `then` won't wait...in your code, you're just logging messages...which is syncronous...so your `then` waits as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to guarantee this, you actually have to return promises from the previous promise.

*Whatever you **return** from a promise will be passed into the next promise.*

In your case, you're returning `undefined`.

If, instead, you returned a promise, then the promise would be resolved, and the second promise would run after that happened, and would be passed whatever value the promise resolved with.

So yes, promises are guaranteed to run one after another, but if you choose to do something async inside of their callback, and don't bother chaining it back into the promise by returning it, then they're not going to bother to wait for anything (because they don't know that there's anything to wait for).

I'm assuming `db.remove` returns a promise...

...so, knowing that we have to return a promise from the callback, in order for it to actually wait for async stuff to happen, I would do something like this.

```
.then(result => Promise.all(result.rows.map(row => db.remove(row.doc))))
.then((listOfRemoves) => console.log(`removed`));
```

Whether the second function takes 1 argument or 0 arguments is 100% inconsequential as to when the second function runs.

### Edit

examples:

```
.then(() => setTimeout(() => console.log('2nd', 20000)))
.then(() => console.log('first'));
```

This happens because the first then has NO idea that there is a setTimeout happening. It's not a mind-reader, it just runs the code and passes the return value along (in this case, `undefined`).

If the return value happens to be a promise, though, it will wait until that promise is done, get the value from it, and pass *that* on.

```
.then(() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 20000)))
.then(() => console.log('I waited 20 seconds.'));
```

Because it's returning a promise, it will call the `then` of that promise, and wait to get the value, to pass on.

The reason your tests are failing is because you're basically doing this.

```
.then(() => console.log('first'))
.then(() => console.log('second'));
```

These are guaranteed to fire in this order. Period.
All of the other ones have been firing in that order as well. It's just that they are *also* scheduling async processes, just like all other callbacks/timeouts that use async I/O in JS.

Comment: Even if the first `.then()` function does not return another promise, the second `.then()` function is still guaranteed to be called after the first one, right? I'm a little confused about the first sentence.

Comment: @PeterMader yes. It's guaranteed to happen after. How many arguments the second function takes is inconsequential. There's no magic here, just some stuff in the promise implementation that you don't have a grasp of yet. In your test, all of your own code is synchronous. If you had put a `setTimeout` in the first function, you'd get the expected result of your second result happening first... ...unless you returned a promise that was resolved when the setTimeout finished, then it would go back to sequential.

Comment: So you don't have to *return promises from the previous promise* to guarantee this (like you are saying in the first sentence).

Comment: The example using `db.remove` is async. Like `setTimeout`, or an AJAX call. Your test is using synchronous code. Promise callbacks have no magic for guessing if there is code inside of the function that is async and needs to be waited for. So just like regular callbacks, the code will move on to the next thing, while waiting for the async code to be scheduled and run. That's why the behaviours diverge.

Comment: @Norguard, Thank you for your answer! I updated the question. Please tell me if I understood it correctly?

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov That's right. I think the code that you have there is probably a little more complex than it needs to be to demonstrate it, but yes. `forEach` returns nothing, and all of your `print` calls are async, so they're all delayed. Because of the combination of those two things, it looks like the promises are running backwards. They aren't, you just aren't waiting. If you wanted to put them back in order, you'd use `return Promise.all(rows.map(...))`, and then it would wait for every one of those `print` calls to be done, before moving onto the next one.